# Цветовая схема PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

Подскажите где можно изменить цвет вводимого текста в панельке "Run", пошарился по настройкам и не нашел ничего.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Для потомков
File -> Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Console Colors -> Console -> User Input